# Blank screen in html website when using IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we are doing a website and got a problem we are unable to fix. There is a login screen which displays a welcome screen after successful login. Everything works fine but not with IE9. After successful login the screen stays blank on IE9.

All files are just html files with javascript and css. Some parts of the site also use jquery.

If anyone has ever encountered this kind of problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

These are the error messages we were receiving when testing with IE9. After a while we were able to remove the errors but the site still stays blank.

```
Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
Line: 1 
Char: 29910 
Code: 0 
URI: server/public/js/javascript1.js 

Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js

Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
Line: 1
Char: 29910
Code: 0
URI: server/public/js/javascript1.js 

Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js

Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js
    
Message: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a         Function object
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: server/public/js/javascript3.js 
   
Message: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a  Function object
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: server/public/js/javascript2.js
```

Comment: Please post you code. Welcome to stackoverflow! :)

Comment: Those errors indicate that jquery is not being loaded and you are attempting to use jquery when you don't have it linked.

Comment: That's because the method `addEventListener` don't work on IE9. You will find this helpful: https://modernizr.com/ ;)

Comment: @Jay He's using v2.1.3, as per the info in the question.

Comment: Great list of error messages, without the code though, totally useless. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)